# How to avoid text-selection contextmenu going inside background

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi i'm facing the problem of text-selection contextmenu going in the background when i select the corner text.

**Question:** How to make text-selection menu always visible by avoiding going inside background as shown below

[image]

Here is what i have tried

```js
document.onselectionchange = () =>{
    var toolbar = document.getElementById('tools_panel');
    console.log('toolbar toolbar',toolbar);

    var sel = getSelection();

    if (sel.rangeCount > 0)
    {
      var ran = sel.getRangeAt(0);

      if (ran.collapsed === false)
      {
        var rect = ran.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rectTop = rect.top;
        var rectCenter = rect.left + (rect.width / 2);

        toolbar.style.display = "";
        toolbar.style.left = (rectCenter - (toolbar.offsetWidth / 2)) + "px";
        toolbar.style.top = (rectTop - toolbar.offsetHeight) + "px";

        if (parseFloat(toolbar.style.top) < 0)
        {
          toolbar.style.top = "0px";
        }
        if (parseFloat(toolbar.style.left) < 0)
        {
          toolbar.style.left = "0px";
        }
        toolbar.style.display = 'block';
        this.isEditorPanelShowed = true;
      }
      else
      {
        toolbar.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    else
    {
      toolbar.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
.tools-ul{
   display: flex;
    list-style: none; 
}

.tools-ul li{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
}

#tools_panel{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="text-selection-area">
  
  Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, ducimus totam quae inventore fuga, ullam velit, corporis eveniet dignissimos deleniti ab necessitatibus adipisci corrupti deserunt possimus earum illo nostrum neque. In, quas vel rerum recusandae officiis, voluptate quidem nostrum dolor fuga corporis delectus debitis perspiciatis aliquid dignissimos quaerat temporibus ex tempore quo provident quam laborum exercitationem? Perferendis, sequi. Id, provident consequatur vel eveniet vero voluptate possimus animi corrupti facilis enim. Voluptatem perspiciatis officia molestias officiis aut, provident adipisci exercitationem tempore corrupti magni temporibus eos quis aspernatur consequuntur quod. Rerum aspernatur exercitationem dolor recusandae numquam modi pariatur temporibus nemo, voluptatem ad veritatis ducimus itaque velit, vitae doloremque necessitatibus, distinctio beatae provident nam consequatur debitis suscipit neque enim! Eos nesciunt inventore consectetur, odio ad non, optio, aspernatur dolor distinctio officiis sint quam corrupti sed voluptatem atque suscipit voluptate harum dolores deleniti facere recusandae. Dolore, quos. Aliquid non similique minima exercitationem dolorem assumenda doloremque eligendi facilis, odit expedita in voluptas eius unde nostrum id harum quisquam. Error similique cum soluta unde at, ipsa laborum quae ad alias laudantium rem. Inventore eligendi minima id consequatur dicta, est totam sit, maiores, eos sunt cupiditate? Molestiae esse labore voluptates, dolor natus aspernatur, non illum libero obcaecati ut alias veritatis reprehenderit praesentium incidunt, suscipit consectetur ex ea autem voluptatem beatae debitis iste! Facilis explicabo asperiores minus cumque. Quam aliquid, possimus nemo saepe amet, maiores debitis iusto tempore soluta repellendus quasi, reprehenderit iste consequuntur expedita optio mollitia. Doloremque enim a quod deleniti voluptates quas nesciunt expedita placeat quam aspernatur itaque officia ad consequatur qui et laudantium similique amet, maiores facilis! Sunt doloribus fugit aspernatur. Eius unde libero ipsum eligendi! Iste quae laboriosam praesentium, at, consectetur modi, maiores non asperiores ullam suscipit doloremque sapiente quis laudantium nobis mollitia totam repellendus eos tempora aliquam reiciendis rerum natus accusamus unde. Odit temporibus repudiandae minus nostrum voluptatum atque hic eum possimus suscipit necessitatibus maiores tenetur asperiores illum eius sapiente voluptas rem soluta, accusamus alias earum incidunt, similique repellendus explicabo. Quo neque doloremque sed iusto laboriosam consequatur, quaerat fugit non accusantium illo corrupti velit ea, deleniti veritatis architecto! Ut sapiente quaerat corrupti ad illum dolorum, voluptates quidem. Nam cumque maxime corporis libero numquam ipsum fuga a nulla temporibus modi ducimus enim minus tempora eum, vitae nemo minima perferendis. Enim illum quidem sunt! Quis saepe earum ea temporibus laboriosam perspiciatis hic, nemo ratione error ad eaque asperiores consequatur in praesentium accusantium, vero laborum dolorem?
  
</div>

<div id="tools_panel" style="position:absolute;background:#eaeaed;padding:3px;">
   <ul class="tools-ul">
     <li>Bold</li>
     <li>Italic</li>
     <li>Underline</li>
     <li>O-list</li>
     <li>U-list</li>
     <li>Fill</li>
     <li>Font +-</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**For better view here is a codepen:**  https://codepen.io/eabangalore/pen/QWxaKNx

Comment: You can monitor the width of your toolbar, when it is larger than the width of your window, set its right position to 0 so it sticks to the right side.

Comment: @dalelandry i have tried what you said above it is working fine , smoothness is not there still i'm trying to make it smooth. thank you for your valuable solution.

Comment: another way of putting it would be if the left position of your toolbar ***(in pixels)*** + its width ***(in pixels)*** is larger than the viewports width ***(in pixels)***, you are overflowing so you can add logic that locks in the right side of your toolbar to the right side of the viewport. As you drag back away from the side, get the mouse position and the width of the toolbar + its left position is less than the viewport of the window remove the css property that locks in the right side of the toolbar with the right side of the viewport.

Comment: Honestly, is there any reason why you are not fixing the toolbar to the viewport using position fixed? You could add logic that locks the top of the of the content editable div below or above your fixed toolbar.